# Why MediaPlayer can't be set in MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, android-mediaplayer

Why when I create the MediaPlayer variable in the Main Activity, the app crashes?

**( This code works fine )**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


MediaPlayer audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_audio);

    public void play(View view){

        audio.start();
    }
    public void pause(View view){
       
            audio.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_audio);

    }
}
```

( But this code doesn't work; the app crashes)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
    MediaPlayer audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_audio);
    
        public void play(View view){
    
            audio.start();
        }
        public void pause(View view){
           
                audio.pause();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

**PLEASE give me an explanation :(**

Answer (score 0):

in second case you havent created `MediaPlayer` instance at all

```
MediaPlayer audio;
```

so every `audio.anyMethodCall()` will throw `NullPointerException`

just keep `audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_audio);` line in `onCreate`, thats proper place for initing player

and please learn some basics about programming...

Comment: Sorry I meant MediaPlayer audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_audio); When I put it in the MainActivity it doesn't work

Comment: you can't init `MediaPlayer` this way, as it needs properly inited `Context` and `Activity extends Context`, so you can pass `this` as `Context` param (first). BUT `Context` need to be "settled up" (thus `Activity` have a [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)) and first moment when you can use this `Activity` as `Context` is `onCreate` method

Comment: btw. I suspect that you are calling `new MainActivity().play()` somewhere - do NOT do that! `Activity`s can be started only using `Intent`, as contextual object it must be initiated by system and related lifecycle methods must be called. when you are creating `new MainActivity()` then its just an object, doesn't show up, `onCreate` isn't called

Answer (score 0):

```
private MediaPlayer audio;
```

oncreate method

```
 audio= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shape_of_you);
                    audio.start();
```

You can do something like this

Comment: Thank you! But why when I create that in the MainActivity it doesn't work ( it works only when I put it in the OnCreate method

Comment: because there is a life cycle method of activity  so it is the 1st thing that came in front so we need to call in onCreate only 
if you want to see the life cycle you can go on this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

The Correct code should be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
    MediaPlayer audio;
    
        public void play(View view){
    
            audio.start();
        }
        public void pause(View view){
           
                audio.pause();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

the only change I did was removing declaration before oncreate method:

**Earlier:**

```
MediaPlayer audio = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_audio);
```

**Correct Code:**

```
MediaPlayer audio;
```

**Explanation:**

1. onCreate()  method is for definition like *adding audio to `MediaPlayer`, defining `textView`, etc,* since onCreate() gets triggered after creation of activity(activity_main).
2. You added audio 2 times, which is not needed, you added an audio at first and then replace it with another audio in onCreate() method